# When does a browser send a conditional get

Tags: performance, http, browser

My understanding is a browser sends a conditional get if it is not sure if the compoonent it has is up to date.  The question is what defines "not sure".  I presume it varys on browser and maybe other conditions.  I also presume it's not something you can control, i.e. I can do anything to make browser change the not sure criteria.  I can't set something in the way I can set an expires header to what I want on a Http server.  Is this correct?

Note:P if you can answer this question with just areally good link that's fine. I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 6):

The HTTP has an [expiration model](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.2). It defines [how servers can specify their responses to expire](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.2.1), and how the [age](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.2.3) and [freshness of a response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.2.4) can be determined by caches. Additionally to that, there are further [*Cache-Control* directives](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9) that can modify the behavior for how responses are to be handled dependent or independent of their freshness.

To conclude, HTTP caching is quite complex and the actual behavior depends on multiple factors:

> The cache-control directives can be broken down into these general categories:
>
> - [Restrictions on what are cacheable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9.1); these may only be imposed by the origin server.
> - [Restrictions on what may be stored by a cache](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9.2); these may be imposed by either the origin server or the user agent.
> - [Modifications of the basic expiration mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9.3); these may be imposed by either the origin server or the user agent.
> - [Controls over cache revalidation and reload](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9.4); these may only be imposed by a user agent.
> - [Control over transformation of entities.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9.5)

But in the end, it all depends on the user agent’s obedience of these rules.